# Bilinear form on $X\times X^*$

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, bilinear-form

Suppose that $X$ is a finite-dimensional Banach space. Let $T\in L(X)$ be an operator on $X$. Then the map $f:X\times X^*\to F$ ($F=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), defined by $f(x,y^*)=y^*(Tx)$ immediately gives us a bilinear form on $X\times X^*$.

Verification: $f(ax_1+bx_2,y^*)=y^*(T(ax_1+bx_2))=y^*(Tax_1)+y^*(Tbx_2)=ay^*(Tx_1)+by^*(Tx_2)=af(x_1,y^*)+bf(x_2,y^*).$

$f(x, ay_1^*+by_2^*)=(ay_1^*+by_2^*)(Tx)=ay_1^*(Tx)+by_2^*(Tx)=af(x,y_1^*)+bf(x,y_2^*).$

But whenever $X$ is Hilbert, we have the following

$f(x,y^*)=y^*(Tx)$. By Riesz Representation theorem, we have $y^*(\cdot)=\langle \cdot, y \rangle$ for some $y\in X$. Thus, we have
$$f(x,y^*)=\langle Tx,y \rangle.$$
Thus, here $f$ becomes conjugate linear in the second component.

The Hilbert space case the particular case of the Banach space case. However, in case of Hilbert space the "bilinear" form becomes conjugate linear.

Why there is such an incompatibility? Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mapping $(x,y)\mapsto f(x, \langle \cdot, y\rangle) = \langle T(x),y \rangle$ of $X\times X\to \Bbb{C}$ is conjugate linear in the second entry, but the mapping $X\times X^*\to\Bbb{C}$ given by $(x,\eta)\mapsto f(x,\eta)=\eta(T(x))$ is bilinear. So, you're basically looking at the wrong function when you said "Thus, here $f$ becomes conjugate linear in second component".

Comment: Indeed, the Riesz identification $X \to X^*$ sending $y \mapsto \langle \cdot, y \rangle$ is a *conjugate* linear isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Riesz Representation theorem says that the function $$\phi : X \to X^*; \quad x\ \mapsto \langle \cdot,x \rangle$$ is a bijective [conjugate-linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map) map. Thus, for $y^* \in X^*$ we have $y^* = \phi(\phi^{-1}(y^*)) = \langle \cdot, \phi^{-1}(y^*) \rangle$ and $$(\forall x \in X) \quad f(x,y^*) = y^*(Tx) = \langle Tx, \phi^{-1}(y^*) \rangle.$$ Since $\phi^{-1}$ and $\langle Tx,\cdot \rangle$ are both conjugate-linear, $\langle Tx,\cdot \rangle \circ \phi^{-1} = f(x,\cdot)$ is linear, and there is no contradiction.